# Conda enviroment with SLURM

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, slurm

I am trying to execute a python script in a conda enviroment on a SLURM cluster. So far any suggestions I found online couldn't solve my problem. I set up my conda enviroment and installed all necessary packages. To keep it simple, let's say that my python script contains only the line `import torch`. The necessary packages are installed in the enviroment (the script runs smoothly on my local computer). I installed Miniconda if this is important.

My bash file contains after `#!/bin/sh` and several `#SBATCH` commands the following lines:

```
source /path/to/.bashrc
conda activate myenv

python3 /path/to/test.py
```

But then I get the error message that the file .bashrc doesn't exist.

If I delete the lines

```
source /path/to/.bashrc
conda activate myenv
```

and execute the bash file from the activated enviroment myenv I get the error message that it cannot find the module torch....

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I needed to install miniconda, create the enviroments, install all the packages etc in the bash script such that the SLURM node has access to it. I then also uninstall conda again at the end of the bash script.

Answer (score 0):

## Load the Conda module

```bash
module purge
module load miniconda

# Activate Conda environment and run the Python script
source /path/to/.bashrc
conda activate myenv
python3 /path/to/test.py
```

Make sure to replace "your_partition" with the actual partition you want to use, and update the paths to your .bashrc file, Conda environment, and Python script accordingly.

Also, ensure that the source /path/to/.bashrc line is necessary. Sometimes, the Conda activation alone might be sufficient. If you still face issues, consider removing or modifying that line.

Remember to make your script executable:

```bash
chmod +x your_script.sh
```

Then, submit the script to SLURM:

```bash
sbatch your_script.sh
```

Comment: Unfortunatley then I get the error message: Lmod has detected the following error: The following module(s) are unknown: "miniconda".
The paths are normally correct, he finds the python file but he just doesn't find the bash file whereby I don't understand why. On the SLURM node I can cd into the directory where the bash file is stored...

Answer (score 0):

Following up with RafMo20D's answer, you'll want to run the [avail](https://curc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compute/modules.html) command while searching for `miniconda` by typing the following into your terminal:

```bash
module avail miniconda
```

This will list the exact miniconda package. For example, something like `miniconda3-4.5.11-gcc-8.2.0-oqs2mbg`.

You'll want to use this exact module name in the script provided above:

```bash
module purge
module load miniconda3-4.5.11-gcc-8.2.0-oqs2mbg

# Activate Conda environment and run the Python script
source /path/to/.bashrc
conda activate myenv
python3 /path/to/test.py
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately `module avail miniconda` returns: No module(s) or extension(s) found! Also the command `module spider` only returns the modules Lmod, mpi and settarg. But there should be a lot more, no?

Comment: Interesting. In that case I'd recommend emailing your sysadmin to find out the name of the `miniconda` package on cluster. 

You could also try typing out `module avail` and scrolling through the list of available modules until you see something that contains the word `miniconda`. Sorry, wish I could provide a more direct answer!